# How to mock protected member of the base class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Why something like this doesn't work:

```
public class BaseFoo{
   protected int FooField;
}

public class FooChild:BaseFoo{

}

var m = new Mock<FooChild>();

m.Protected().Setup<int>("FooField").Returns(1);
```

It says "Member FooChild.FooProp doesn't exist"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh.. I see.. it has to be a property not a field and it has to be `protected virtual`

Answer (score 0):

If any variable of parent class is protected then it can be accessed in child class, but it cannot be accessed in class which will extend or use child class.